# Upload big file to OneDrive cloud storage

Tags: zip

I want to back up a lot of my files (photos, videos ...) to cloud storage. 
My idea was to create a (700 GB big) ZIP file and upload it to OneDrive, where I have 1 TB of space. But, OneDrive has limited file size to 15 GB. Just for information, Google Drive has 5 TB file size limitation, pCloud unlimited ...

If I stay with OneDrive, I can prepare multiple ZIP files. 
And here I have two questions:
1. If one file will be damaged/missing, is extracting (rest of the archive) from multiple ZIP possible?
2. Any other idea how to backup 700 GB of photos to OneDrive?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of making a zip file? Most people sync their files directly to OneDrive.

Comment: @Appleoddity - my first thought was that handling one file would be much simpler. But on the other hand: compression won't be a point here (JPGs), the single photo can't be fast extracted on any place ... So now I'm thinking of simple copy. Syncing to OneDrive isn't enabled on my computer (I'm using pCloud which is way better service).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can compress a file that much especially multimedia, and I wouldn't advise uploading 700gb of data at once unless your on a symmetrical gigabit connection. I have decent upload speeds around 60Mbps but that would take me a long time so long my computer would probably crash or I would get tired of having a dedicated uploader hogging up system and network resources.

I would suggest some free alternative but there are prerequisites both in terms of hardware and knowledge.

1. Nextcloud provides a completely free service as long as you can set
           it up. If you have redundant storage it is a pretty safe way of
           deploying your own cloud. Barring natural disasters but those can be
           accounted for by having a backup server set up in a remote location. It has 
           good apps for IOS and Android so you can backup
       pictures on the go and your initial backup over LAN wouldnt take
       that long. Get some old computers throw a few hardrives in them and linux is your best friend. Especially with the use of Docker containers set up is a breeze.
2. Another option is backing up that data on an old computer and have a
   friend or family member who lives far away keep an identical copy
   somewhere you could sync them once a month.
3. The cheapest option is getting some external hard drives ive had both 2.5 and 3.5 inch hard drives be reliable for 3-4 years on average. Keep one hard drive at home back up all your data clone it on a second hard drive and put that in a storage container. You can use something like rsync or even a copy + paste to keep them updated.
4. Another option is having a redundant storage server at home so if
   one hard drive fails you replace it and hopefully they fail one at a
   time

.Hope this helps. If you go for the first option I'd be happy to guide you through the process.

Comment: The cloud isn't actually in the clouds lol, I would imagine super users are enthusiasts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have a copy on an external disk. I want to have a cloud copy - one reason is second back up, another reason is availability from every place (but this isn't practical if all files are ZIPed and I'm thinking to have simple copies of files).